# How to use refresh token in request header?

Tags: python, django, api, python-requests

I have a Django project. In this project I am using an API.
I get data from this API with python requests.

When I am using "access token" for request header it works but in the end of several time it logouts, so I want to use "refresh_token" instead of access_token.

How can I do that?

```
credit = requests.get(settings.API_ADDRESS + "analyze/scoring/" + id, 
                      headers={'Authorization': settings.API_TOKEN})  
...
API_ADDRESS = "https://api.myaddress.com/"
API_TOKEN = "Bearer <access_token>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use this credit more than once ?

You should make a call of an API once,get the response in a json and then you can use it as the dict. Like so:

```
credit = requests.get(settings.API_ADDRESS + "analyze/scoring/" + id, 
                  headers={'Authorization': settings.API_TOKEN})
response = credit.json()
for data in response['results']
      data[''] 
      ....
```

and if you need other info you just redo your call to the API